# Custom Cell in UITableView won't reload correctly after data in the cell is changed

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I've created a custom cell in a `UITableView`.  The style is set to Custom.  The identifier is set to customCell. The Accessory is set to Detail. The Table View content is set to Dynamic Prototypes.

The table is loaded with data from core data and appears just perfectly when it first appears.  When the user taps the detail icon in the cell, a segue to a new view appears so the user can edit the data in the cell and save it to core data.  When the user is done editing and taps the Save button, the view returns to the `UITableView` but the cell that has just been edited appears as a 'Basic' cell and not the customCell.  If I tap on the cell, it highlights and the custom cell contents appear OVER the basic cell contents.

I can't seem to be able to resolve this.  Can anyone suggest something?

Here is the section of `prepareForSegue` that sends to the editing view controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell*)sender {

if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"editPunchItemSegue"]) {
// DEFINE SEGUE DESTINATION
UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
EditPunchItemViewController *editPunchItemViewController = (EditPunchItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
Punchitem *editPunchItem = (Punchitem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

editPunchItemViewController.editPunchitem = editPunchItem;
```

And now, in the destination View Controller, where the core data is edited, here is a portion of the saveButtonPressed method:

```
 if  ([_editSaveButton.title isEqualToString:@"Save"]) {
    NSLog(@"Save Button has been PRESSED");

    editPunchitem.punchitemRoomNumber = _editPunchitemRoomNumberField.text;
    editPunchitem.punchitemDescription = _editPunchitemDescriptionField.text;
    editPunchitem.punchitemLocation = _editPunchitemLocationField.text;
    editPunchitem.punchitemRoomName = _editPunchitemRoomNameField.text;
    editPunchitem.punchitemDate = _editPunchitemDateField.text;

    // SAVE TO MANAGE OBJECT CONTEXT!
    [super saveAndDismiss];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Here is my cellForRowAtIndex in the TableViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

//  USING CUSTOM PROTOTYPE CELL:
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Punchitem *punchitem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//  USING CUSTOM PROTOTYPE CELL:
    cell.cellLocationLabel.text = punchitem.punchitemLocation;
    cell.cellDescriptionLabel.text = punchitem.punchitemDescription;
    cell.cellRoomNameLabel.text = punchitem.punchitemRoomName;

    return cell;
}
```

Save and dismiss is part of a subclass.  Here is the method:

```
-(void) saveAndDismiss {

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {  //SAVE FAILED
            NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE FAILED! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"SAVE SUCCEEDED!");
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what does save and dissmiss do, and please show cellAtRowIndex, it looks like somehting is overwriting your storyboard

Comment: I just added my cellForRowAtIndex in my original posting

Comment: Try to use xib prototype cell.

Comment: very nice solution found for this in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

did you try reloading the table when you are back from EditPunchItemViewController ?

put in the master viewController :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   if (self.tableView) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have that very line in my TableViewController's viewWillAppear.  Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have something like this

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
```

If yes, are you sure to call this when finished

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Most of the time we use this with NSFetchedResultsController...

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
...
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for this suggestion but I have both of these methods already included in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Last option, you have to conditional debug...

All in your Main ViewController :

1) add a property

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *DEBUGindexPath;
```

2) set DEBUGindexPath in

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell*)sender {

if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"editPunchItemSegue"]) {
...
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
DEBUGindexPath = indexPath;
...
```

3) Add a BreakPoint in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Edit the breakpoint to set condition :

```
(self.DEBUGindexPath.row == indexPath.row) && (self.DEBUGindexPath.section == indexPath.section)
```

Don't set Automatically continue...

Ok, now run your app. When you will be back from EditPunchItemViewController, the break point should trigger only for the selected row. Go step by step to check if you can found something

Answer (score 0):

> the view returns to the UITableView but the cell that has just been edited appears as a 'Basic' cell and not the customCell.

Look at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` carefully, the following condtion:

```
    //USING CUSTOM PROTOTYPE CELL:
    CustomTableViewCell *cell =
                    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

When the cell is nil you set its style to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` but you forget to set its accessory type through the code.

So just make sure set its accessory type in that if statement like this:

```
    //USING CUSTOM PROTOTYPE CELL:
    CustomTableViewCell *cell =
                    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //Set accessory to Detail
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
    }
```

---

Here's the complete list of style:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

Comment: I don't understand.  I am using a custom cell.  When the table view loads, I get a Basic view instead of my custom view.  Where do I add the line cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton to make sure the custom cell appears and not the basic cell?   Should I be using something other than UITableViewCellStyleDefault?

Comment: @Jupiter869 Im sorry I was not so clear, see my edit

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no effect.  When I return from the EditView to the TableView, the cell appears as a "Basic" cell with one line of data in it rather than the "customCell" I had set up in storyboard.  If I click in the cell, it highlights and both the 'Basic' and 'customCell" appear on top of each other.  It appears as if the 'Basic' cell is on TOP of the 'customCell'.  It is baffling and terribly frustrating to me.

Comment: This shot shows the tableView upon first loading: http://imgur.com/sPoazwi  - This next shot shows the tableView after the second cell has been edited.  Notice that the cell shows a Basic cell format: http://imgur.com/TSFct3J   - Last image shows what happens when i click the second cell.  The customCell appears on top of the Basic cell:  http://imgur.com/uHtSoon

Comment: @Jupiter869 you are using a prototype cell?

Comment: my tableView is set to Dynamic Prototypes in the Storyboard

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48899/discussion-between-meda-and-jupiter869)